# Fantasy Novel Involving Magical Colored Thread

Tags: identification-request

### What

A medium length paperback fantasy novel, probably YA, with a chosen-one style male main character. The setting is fantasy, but not high fantasy and did not contain elves, dragons, etc.
There are two distinct parts that I remember.

#### Magical Rope Material

In the series, there is some form of magical material that is quite potent and probably rare. We eventually learn that it can be fashioned into some form of cord/thread/rope/etc. with different colors that have magical power / potency. By combining them in specific ways they can do important things.

#### Mountain Ascent Scene

There is a scene where the protagonist climbs above the clouds up some mountain or structure and discovers that the antagonists have been fashioning a giant network/lattice of the rope between the mountains that acts as a magical super-structure. It has been built to produce some terrifyingly powerful magical effect. It may have been intended to completely change or end the world.

I believe the protagonist dismantles / modifies the structure to avert this calamity and potentially bring about some good end instead.

The protagonist does not know that he will find the structure up there, but for some reason (maybe a mentor/wise figure told him to) he knows that he will find something there and must go look.

### When

I read this book as a teenager in middle or high school between sometime between 2008-2014. The book did not seem super old or super new, so it probably came out in the preceding few years or if it was new there wasn't any buzz about it.

### Where

I probably found this book in my local library in North Carolina. The book was in English.

### Other

For some reason I associate it in my head with Seeker (2005). Possibly because I read it at a similar time? From the synopsis I have read online, this does not appear to be the correct book/series.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! This is an excellent amount of information, nice work. However, I'm still going to point you to the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) in case you haven't seen it yet. Some further questions: do you remember anything about the cover? Or the format (ebook vs hardcover vs softcover etc.)?

Comment: I have added that it was a paperback book, I do not remember the cover

Comment: Would it be one of the Circle of Magic books, by Tamora Pierce? I think one of those was about a thread mage.

Comment: Did you find the book in a library in Charlotte? If so, we picked up the same book and I’m trying to also remember the name. Did it start off with the main character being raised by his mother and his grandparents?